# How to search PHP multidimensional by value and get another values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [cast_id] => 45 [character] => Evelyn Salt [credit_id] => 52fe4555c3a368484e054141 [gender] => 1 [id] => 11701 [name] => Angelina Jolie [order] => 0 [profile_path] => /6tocswK39SrSjZIRDaTpVyPxDz8.jpg )
[1] => Array ( [cast_id] => 3 [character] => Theodore Winter [credit_id] => 52fe4555c3a368484e05409f [gender] => 2 [id] => 23626 [name] => Liev Schreiber [order] => 1 [profile_path] => /qFn3npmqd1qaYOk6yohmi3FbPhc.jpg )
[2] => Array ( [cast_id] => 4 [character] => Darryl Peabody [credit_id] => 52fe4555c3a368484e0540a3 [gender] => 2 [id] => 5294 [name] => Chiwetel Ejiofor [order] => 2 [profile_path] => /fwaEgwYJdzGyBmGcHiH13vobQii.jpg )
[3] => Array ( [cast_id] => 10 [character] => Oleg Vasilyevich Orlov [credit_id] => 52fe4555c3a368484e0540bb [gender] => 2 [id] => 7107 [name] => Daniel Olbrychski [order] => 3 [profile_path] => /nfqJ8xiVNyBQQhnYRkwJzl3iS7s.jpg ))
```

I need to search for names where gender = 2.

Now I use this code:

```
function searcharray($value, $gender, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $a => $val) {
       if ($val[$gender] == $value) {
           return $val['name'];
       }
   }
   return null;
}
$iro = searcharray('2', gender, $array);
```

But it gives me just the first one: Liev Schreiber.
I need all of them separated with ",".

Comment: $res[] = $val['name']; and return implode(',', $res);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you put a return statement in the middle of a cycle. This way, the first match will terminate the function execution.
For this to work you should first declare an empty results array and push in it every matching value. After every element of the array has been checked and the foreach finishes you can return the imploded array to get all the names separated by comma.
With all this in mind the correct function will be the following:

```
function searcharray($value, $gender, $array) {
   $results = [];
   foreach ($array as $a => $val) {
       if ($val[$gender] == $value) {
           array_push($results, $val['name']);
       }
   }
   return implode(',', $results);
}
$iro = searcharray('2', gender, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
function searcharray($value, $gender, $array) {  
  $arrNames = [];    
  foreach ($array as $a => $val) {
       if ($val[$gender] == $value) {
           $arrNames[]= $val['name'];
       }    
   }    
  return $arrNames;

}
```